# How do I create a dynamic URL structure based on database values?

Tags: php, mysql, url, dynamic

I have been looking for a solution on how to create dynamic URLs driven by mysql database values.

Currently, I have been manually creating the directory structure which includes various php pages.

URL Logic: site.com/**city-name/name-of-development**/ {then} (index.php, profile.php, map.php, 
etc.)

ie. site.com/**fort-lauderdale/turnberry-condos**/index.php

For ease of updating the site, the coding for each of these pages are imported from files in "/include" directory in the root directory. (for whatever that's worth)

All the elements to create the desired URL are contained within each database record. So my question is; **how do I dynamically create directories or virtual-directories (which may not actually reside on the server) based on database values?**

AND I would also appreciate any feedback on how such dynamic structures would affect a search engine's ability to crawl/index these pages?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained and use the queries you rewrite to pass the correct info to your PHP pages

Comment: @ChenAsraf is correct regarding the general concept of how to do this. Or, you could use a framework that already supports this. In terms of search engines, it's not a problem.